# How to set up Environment variable for using Jython in Weka

Tags: environment-variables, weka, jython

[Instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwbPzumwgNo) on how to set up Jython in weka, especially on setting Environment variable for accessing dataset files, made it clear and easy for windows user, but no information was given for Mac user.

I wonder how to set up Environment variable in Mac for Jython in weka to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. After the installation of Jython and JFreeChart library from Weka Package manager;
2. go to home directory's terminal, enter `nano .bash_profile`
3. inside `.bash_profile`, add a line of code as below

`export Weka_Data=User/Documents/Directory/Of/Your/Data`

4. save and exit
5. inside terminal run `source .bash_profile`

Now, Environment variable for Jython in weka to access dataset is all set.